# Implement Type 2 table - merge query

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery, type-2-dimension

I have a current table:

| ID | Name | Salary | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 50,000 | Active |
| 2 | Joe | 55,000 | Active |
| 3 | Jake | 40,000 | Inactive |
| 4 | James | 80,000 | Active |

This table is created using a truncate reload query. However I want to now record historical data using a type 2 table. I know I need to add a start and end date field to indicate whether a row is the current or historical data for an employee.

Lets say the next day the source table looks like such:

| ID | Name | Salary | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 55,000 | Active |
| 2 | Joe | 55,000 | Inactive |
| 3 | Jake | 40,000 | Inactive |
| 4 | James | 80,000 | Active |

Where John got a increase Salary, and Joe is now inactive.

I want my Type 2 table to now look like:

| ID | Name | Salary | Status | start date | end date | active flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 55,000 | Active | 10-26-2022 | null | Y |
| 1 | John | 50,000 | Active | 10-25-2022 | 10-26-2022 | N |
| 2 | Joe | 55,000 | Active | 10-26-2022 | null | Y |
| 2 | Joe | 55,000 | Inactive | 10-25-2022 | 10-26-2022 | N |
| 3 | Jake | 40,000 | Inactive | 10-26-2022 | null | Y |
| 4 | James | 80,000 | Active | 10-26-2022 | null | Y |

I am not familiar with creating a merge query to create this sort of performance, how can I go about doing so?

Comment: 'MERGE' syntax is product specific. Please tag your question with the specific database that you're using. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Okay apologies, marked with google big query